# How to use cert-manager to manage kubeadm-installed cluster client auth certificates

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, cert-manager

I have a kubernetes cluster which is installed and managed using `kubeadm`. `kubeadm` manages the CA for all cluster certificates and therefore when creating certificates for operator authentication, this is (I assume) the CA that is used.

Instead of needing to manually create and rotate these certificates for access to the cluster, is there a good way to use `cert-manager` to manage these certificates for me?

My current drafted solution is to load the `kubeadm` CA certificate and key into a kubernetes secret, create a `cert-manager` Issuer to use the CA, referencing the secret, and create Certificates using that issuer. Is this a reccomended approach?

Comment: FWIW, I originally asked this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323038/how-to-use-cert-manager-to-manage-kubeadm-installed-cluster-client-auth-certific) but it was closed as off topic, so I hope this is now the "correct" place to ask.